# wishart stochastic volatility models

Tags: stochastic-volatility

Stochastic volatility models assume that volatility follow a random process.In the emerging market the volatility tend to be high. 
why is it that the wishart stochastic volatility model fit well the emerging market

Comment: Do you have a source for the statement that "the wishart stochastic volatility model fits well the emerging markets".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Wishart stochastic volatility model identifies the volatility of the asset as the trace of a [Wishart process](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3256v1.pdf). Contrary to a classic multifactor Heston model, this model allows to add degrees of freedom with regard to the stochastic correlation. Thanks to its flexibility, this model enables a better fit of market data than the Heston model. Besides, the Wishart volatility model keeps a clear interpretation of its parameters and conserves an efficient tractability.It was showed that calibration of Wishart stochastic volatility model is easier than SV model.